# require.js shim, export myOwnGlobal name

Tags: requirejs, require

I'm not sure about the use of "exports" on shim config, following the example on the requireJS API, I can use Backbone (B in capital letter) to export it to a global scope.
This means that it will be a window object property.
But I realized that I'm forced to use that name, and I can't export it by other reference name, ie: "MyGlobalBackbone"

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    backboneAlias:'backbone'
  },
  shim : {
    backboneAlias : {
      deps : [ 'underscore', 'jquery-1.9.1' ],
      exports  : 'MyGlobalBackbone'
    }
  }
});

require(['backboneAlias'],function(backboneAsAliasDependency){
  console.log(backboneAsAliasDependency);//Loaded Ok
  console.log(MyGlobalBackbone); //Uncaught ReferenceError: MyGlobalBackbone is not     defined 
});
```

This code only works if I use "Backbone" instead of "MyGlobalBackbone"...

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by this aliasing?

Answer (score 7):

Actually you got it the other way around: shimming doesn't export a variable to global scope, it *imports* it FROM the global scope. The name ("Backbone") was set by Backbone's author, and this is the part you're explaining to RequireJS in `shim` config element.

Comment: then why does shim has an exports tag?

Comment: @danielrvt you can make it easier by remembering to always read it from the shimmed library's point of view, e.g. *"Backbone: (I'm) depending on jQuery, (I'm) exporting 'Backbone' variable (to global scope)"*

Answer (score 0):

See it in the API:
http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim

Look at this sentence:

//Once loaded, use the global 'Backbone' as the
//module value.

Let's see it in that way, you will understand it:

//Once loaded, `use a global variable 'Backbone' that defined by the backbone vendor` as the
//module value.

Answer (score -1):

You should use **map** to make an alias.

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    ...
  },
  shim : {
    ...
  },
  map: {
      '*': {
          'MyGlobalBackbone': 'Backbone'
      }
  }
});
```

This will allow you to use **MyGlobalBackbone** instead of **Backbone** for all (*) modules.