# What is RequireJS shim exports for?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I'm reading through [Backbone Fundamentals](http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals/) and am currently on the [section](http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals/#exercise-3-your-first-modular-backbone-requirejs-app) that describes how to build an app with RequireJS.

From what I understand, the idea behind shimming is that normally when you require modules, RequireJS figures out how to load their dependencies as well. But when you're trying to load a non-AMD module, this doesn't work (I don't know why, but that's a separate question). To get around this, you could set up a shim to say, "load X before Y".

```
require.config({
  shim: {
    'Y': ['X']
  }
});
```

I see that you could use `exports` to say, "put this non-AMD thing into a global variable instead of a module".

```
require.config({
  shim: {
    'Y': {
      exports: 'globalY'
    }
  }
});
```

Um, what problem does that solve? Isn't the problem with non-AMD libraries just that RequireJS can't figure out the dependencies?

Answer (score 13):

The "I don't know why" part actually needs to be addressed to answer the question. Shimming is *only* required for non-AMD modules, and loading a non-AMD module via RequireJS doesn't work *precisely* because RequireJS requires AMD modules. That is, it needs the module to be wrapped in a `define` call that contains a list of dependencies and a factory method ([more details here](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html#amd)). "Standard", old-style libraries write their stuff into the global scope, into an arbitrarily named namespace (in Backbone's case: `window.Backbone`). Historically, the devs would write a tiny wrapper module to convert "old" library into AMD, e.g.:

**backbone-wrapper.js**

```
define([], function() {
  return window.Backbone;
});
```

Adding shim configuration ([added in RequireJS 2.0](https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/wiki/Upgrading-to-RequireJS-2.0#shim)) allowed dealing with this declaratively in the configuration.

Shimming **is not** saying *"put this non-AMD thing into a global variable instead of a module"*. Shimming is saying "load this non-AMD library and expose the global namespace specified in the `exports` variable as if it was an AMD module".

---

It's actually nicely explained in [RequireJS's documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim) and some other SO questions: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15471088/1240557), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17538713/1240557).